# Determinant of $n\times n$ matrix - two diagonals and a corner

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, alternative-proof

Suppose we have matrix which has zeroes everywhere with the exception of bottom left corner, main diagonal and right above the main diagonal
$$A_n=\begin{pmatrix}
  b_1 & c_1 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & b_2 & c_2 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & b_3 & \ddots &  &  & \vdots \\
  \vdots &  &  & \ddots & \ddots &  & \vdots \\
  \vdots &   &   &   & b_{n-2} & c_{n-2} & 0 \\
  0 &   &   &   & 0 & b_{n-1} & c_{n-1} \\
  c_n & 0 & \ldots & \ldots & 0 & 0 & b_n \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

If we look at [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants), we can see that there only two permutations where we have no zereos. (Namely the identity permutation and shift by one place.) From this we get for the determinant:
$$D_n=\det(A_n) = b_1b_2\cdots b_n + (-1)^{n-1}c_1c_2\dots c_n$$
This is also the solution given in this question: [How to find the determinant of this matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917378)

Are there some other interesting ways to derive this expression for the determinant?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straightforward (interesting?) to do the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) along the first column or the last row since cofactors are determinants of triangular matrices, e.g. for the first column
\begin{align}
D_n&=b_1
\begin{vmatrix}
b_2 &&&&\\
0&b_3 &&&\\
0 &0&b_4&\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\ddots &\\
0&0&0&\ldots&b_n
\end{vmatrix}+(-1)^{n-1}c_n
\begin{vmatrix}
c_1 &0&0&\ldots&0\\
&c_2 &0&\ldots&0\\
&&c_3&\\
&&&\ddots &\vdots\\
&&&&c_{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=b_1b_2\ldots b_n+(-1)^{n-1}c_1c_2\ldots c_n.
\end{align}